When the input size larger, my code won't work, what's the possible explanation
When the input size n is close to 200,000, I always get WA in the first output line not MLE, RE or TLE, but the code work perfectly fine with smaller n size in the online judge and on my local machine with size 200,000 input.  What are the possible problems in my code?
Here is my code:
#define STR_SIZE 20

int main() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    getchar(); //to clear the \n left in the stdin
    char **arr = (char **)calloc(num, sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr[i] = calloc(STR_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        fgets(arr[i], STR_SIZE, stdin);
        arr[i][strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0; //clear trailing space
    }
    //to scan the index need to be searched and print
    int searched_index;
    while (scanf("%d", &searched_index) == 1) {
        if (temp < 0 && temp > num) {
            printf("out of bound");
        }
        printf("%s\n", arr[temp]);
    }
    // Free allocated memory later
    return 0;
}

input example is as follows
3 //how many addressed to be recorded
abcd1111 //address of index 0
abcd2222 //address of index 1
abcd3333 //address of index 2
2 1 //the index of the address to be searched

output example is as follows
abcd3333 //address of index 2
abcd2222 //address of index 1

What I have tried to solve this problem: I already make sure the output format is correct. Time and memory complexity is within the requirements. The gcc arguments are the same as required by online judge.

The provided code does not even compile. Are you absolutely sure STR_SIZE is 20, not 21 (20 characters + null terminator)?

Never edit out #include directives or any other parts of the code. If the compiler needs it, I ned it.

There are multiple problems in the code:

you do not include <stdio.h> at the beginning of the source code (or maybe you omitted this line in the post).
you do not check the return value of the first scanf().
you do not check for allocation failure.
you do not check the return value of fgets().
the test if (temp < 0 && temp > num) is always false unless num is negative. you should write if (temp < 0 || temp >= num).  Furthermore you still access arr[temp] if the test fails.
the variable temp is not defined. Did you mean searched_index? Post the code that you actually tried and the behavior you observe and expect.
as commented by @JohnBollinger, STR_SIZE allows for 19 bytes ber line including the newline, which might be too small for some of the input lines, causing the array to fall out of sync with the file and the subsequent calls to scanf() to read inappropriate data.  Checking that a newline is present in the line read by fgets() is an easy fix for this problem.

It is unclear what you mean by WA, MLE, RE or TLE...
Here is a modified version with error checking:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    char buf[LINE_SIZE];
    int num;
    char eol[2];

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)
    ||  sscanf(buf, "%d%1[\r\n]", &num, eol) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing number of lines\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (num <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid number of lines: %d\n", num);
        return 1;
    }

    char **arr = (char **)calloc(num, sizeof(char *));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d lines\n", num);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "missing data at line %d\n", i + 2);
            return 1;
        }
        size_t pos = strcspn(buf, "\r\n");
        if (buf[pos] == '\0') {
            int c;
            fprintf(stderr, "line %d too long (truncated)\n", i + 2);
            // read and discard the rest of the line
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
        } else {
            buf[pos] = '\0'; // clear line terminator
        }
        arr[i] = strdup(buf);
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for line %d\n", i + 2);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // read index numbers for lines to print
    int index;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d%1[\r\n]", &index, eol) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing index: %s\n", buf);
        } else
        if (index < 0 || index >= num) {
            fprintf(stderr, "index %d out of bounds\n", index);
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", arr[index]);
        }
    }
    // Free allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}


Other possible issues include incorrect dimensions.  STR_SIZE must accommodate data + line terminator + string terminator at each line, else the code as written will fall out of sync with the input.

@JohnBollinger: good point.

Aside: instead of sscanf(buf, "%d%1[\r\n]", &num, eol), I find int n=0; if (sscanf(buf, "%d %n", &num, &n) == 1 && buf[n] == 0) a kinder and better check.

@chux: your version allows for trailing whitespace, which is fine, but uses %n which is considered a potential security flaw and may be disabled on some targets. I would favor if (sscanf(buf, "%d %c", &num, eol) == 1) which is simpler anyway.  There is another issue at stake: I actually mean to match the newline in the buffer to ensure that fgets() did not read a partial line.  Lines with very long sequences of whitespace can be crafted to try and break simple parsers, enforcing proper syntax is a useful defensive approach.

@chqrlie "but uses %n which is considered a potential security flaw and may be disabled on some targets." --> are you sure than applies to *scanf() calls and not just *printf() ones?  Example

@chqrlie  sscanf(buf, "%d %n", &num, &n) approach does have a nice advantage when a trailing non-white-sapce is expected like sscanf(buf, " [%d ] %n", &num, &n).

@chux: you are correct, my mistake: %n is fine for *scanf.
